# Neo4j Date conversion and comparison?

Tags: ms-access, neo4j

I was working with MS access database.MY datetime is now like "05-03-2016 14:55:20" .I need to convert it into datetime format in neo4j.1.How to do it ? 2.After conversion  I need to use date filter i.e I want to find all nodes created between 2 dates.How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If Neo4j is pulling data from Access query, construct field in query that calculates date to a string that Neo4j can then convert to date with its DateTime function.

`Format([fieldname], "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss")`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the APOC function `apoc.date.parse()` to convert your MS Access datetime string into the number of seconds from the UNIX epoch, and then construct a neo4j `datetime` from that value. For example, this will return a neo4j `datetime` that represents your sample time string:

   ```
   RETURN datetime({
     epochSeconds: apoc.date.parse('05-03-2016 14:55:20', 's', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
   })
   ```
2. A neo4j temporal type can only be compared directly to the same type. For instance, to compare a `datetime` X to a `date` Y, you can convert X to a `date` before doing the comparison. The following sample query will return `true`:

   ```
   WITH
     datetime({
       epochSeconds: apoc.date.parse('05-03-2016 14:55:20', 's', 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
     }) AS X,
     date('2016-05-04') AS Y
   RETURN date({date: X}) <= Y
   ```